# No kernel appearing in VS Code in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I use VSCode to run .ipynb notebooks. I have the `Jupyter` extension in VSCode, I also have the `jupyter` package installed (I can see it running `conda list`, for example), but **I cannot run the notebook**. I run a Windows machine.

I can still select an interpreter in VS (`Python 3.9.12 ('base') ~\anaconda3\python.exe,` in my case) but when I try to run the file the next message appears:

[image]

> Type to choose a kernel source

And the thing is no available kernel appears.

I have opened the Jupyter Notebook in my Google Chrome via the Anaconda Navigator and found no problem with that. But I couldn't find any information on how to fix it in VisualStudio Code.

Comment: There's a very slim chance that this is a rendering bug. with my chromium-based apps, sometimes I get rendering issues and need to perform some action to trigger rendering updates. Ex. scrolling. In this particular case, what if you try pressing the up and down arrow keys? Also, is there any additional info in your output logs? (View > Output > various output channels)

Comment: Could you please enable logging as follows: 1. Open settings & go into Jupyter->Logging 2. Change the value to verbose 3. Reload VS Code 4. Attempt to repro the issue & then copy the output from the Jupyter output panel. BTW, if you switch to the pre-release version of jupyter, will it help?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I have changed the log output as you said but nothing changes. The output I get from opening the file is the following: "Experiment 'pythonPromptNewFormatterExt' is active
Experiment 'pythonPromptNewToolsExt' is active
Python interpreter path: ~\anaconda3\python.exe
> conda info --json
Starting Pylance language server.
Send text to terminal: C:/Users/ignac/anaconda3/Scripts/activate
Send text to terminal: C:/Users/ignac/anaconda3/Scripts/activate
Send text to terminal: conda activate base
Send text to terminal: conda activate base"

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT But nothing appears when trying to run the file, I mena, when trying to select the non-existing kernel. I guess that is the output I get by simply opening VS in a python environment (?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Windows machine. It disappeared after upgrading both the Python and the Jupyter plugin.
You can also try uninstalling and re-installing these plugins.

Comment: upgrading to what versions specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading the Jupyter extension to `v2023.10.1003070148` resolved this for me.